# How to test business logic methods using moq and xunit?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, moq, xunit

I'm using generic repository pattern and
this code from my business logic.

```
public class FolderManager : GenericManager<Folder>, IFolderService
{
    private readonly IGenericDal<Folder> _genericDal;
    private readonly IFolderDal _folderDal;
    public FolderManager(IFolderDal folderDal,IGenericDal<Folder> genericDal) : base(genericDal)
    {
        _genericDal = genericDal;
        _folderDal = folderDal;
    }

    public async Task<List<Folder>> GetFoldersByUserId(int id)
    {
        return await _genericDal.GetAllByFilter(I => I.AppUserId == id && I.IsDeleted == false && I.ParentFolderId==null);
    } ...another methods
```

IFolderService Interface :

```
public interface IFolderService : IGenericService<Folder>
{
    Task<List<Folder>> GetFoldersByUserId(int id);
}     ...another methods
```

I want to test `GetFoldersByUserId(int id)` method and i tried this :

```
public class FolderServiceTest
{  
    private readonly FolderManager _sut;
    private readonly Mock<IGenericDal<Folder>> _folderRepoMock = new Mock<IGenericDal<Folder>>();
    private readonly Mock<IFolderDal> _folderDalMock = new Mock<IFolderDal>();
    public FolderServiceTest()
    {
        _sut = new FolderManager(_folderDalMock.Object, _folderRepoMock.Object);
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task GetFoldersByUserId_ShouldReturnListOfFolders_WhenUserExist()
    {
        //Arrange
        Mock<IFolderService> folderServiceMock = new Mock<IFolderService>();
        folderServiceMock.Setup(x => x.GetFoldersByUserId(It.IsAny<int>())).ReturnsAsync(GetSampleFolder);
        
        var expected = GetSampleFolder();

        //Act
         
        //returns null beacuse _sut does not work with the setup I wrote above
        //how can i test this method ? 
        var actual = await _sut.GetFoldersByUserId(1); /* */

        //Assert 
        Assert.Equal(expected.Count, actual.Count);

        for (int i = 0; i < expected.Count; i++)
        {
            Assert.Equal(expected[i].FolderName, actual[i].FolderName);
            Assert.Equal(expected[i].Size, actual[i].Size);
        } 
    }
```

When I start the test, the actual value is null and the test fails. `GetSampleFolder` method has a list of Folders and return this list. My question is how to test `GetFoldersByUserId(int id)` method ?

Comment: Your code looks inconsistent: 1. Why are you defining `folderServiceMock`? 2. What is `IUserService` you are talking about? 3. What is the meaning of "dont accept constructor"? `GetFoldersByUserId` calls `_genericDal` which is `_folderRepoMock` in your test setup. It returns null because you didnt set up `_folderRepoMock.GetAllByFilter` method to return anything so the mock returns null and your `GetFoldersByUserId` returns this null.

Comment: Thank you i think i get it. I wrote folderServiceMock because i thought i can use that in _sut object. I edited comment line in the code above.  I setup `_folderRepoMock.Setup(x => x.GetAllByFilter(I => I.AppUserId == It.IsAny<int>() && I.IsDeleted == false && I.ParentFolderId == null)).ReturnsAsync(GetSampleFolder)` and i get same error. Do you have any idea?

Comment: You missed to add the most important thing: the error itself :) `NotSupportedException: Unsupported expression: I => (((I.AppUserId == IsAny()) AndAlso (I.IsDeleted == False)) AndAlso (I.ParentFolderId == null))` right?

Comment: Sorry i forgot to add. I get this error  `System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` and it's coming from `Assert.Equal(expected.Count, actual.Count);` line. I debugged the test code and i saw `actual` returns null

Comment: You get nullrefex when you skip `_folderRepoMock` setup. But when you do the necessary `_folderRepoMock` setup you will get the notsupex I mention. That is because Moq doesnt support matching on lamba expressions.

Comment: What is the signature of `GetAllByFilter`? `Task<List<T>> GetAllByFilter(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter)` ?

Comment: Yes my `GetAllByFilter` method is :  `public async Task<List<T>> GetAllByFilter(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter)
        {
            using var context = new FilemanagementContext();
            return await context.Set<T>().Where(filter).ToListAsync();
        }`  it's coming from data access layer by the way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The test below shows how to appropriately setup mocks.

The tricky part is the matching on expression, which is not supported by Moq.
That's why I used `It.IsAny` matcher there.

```csharp
[Fact]
public async Task GetFoldersByUserId_ShouldReturnListOfFolders_WhenUserExist()
{
    //Arrange
    var expected = GetSampleFolder();

    var _folderRepoMock = new Mock<IGenericDal<Folder>>();
    _folderRepoMock
        .Setup(x => x.GetAllByFilter(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<Folder, bool>>>()))
        .ReturnsAsync(expected);

    var _folderDalMock = new Mock<IFolderDal>();

    var _sut = new FolderManager(_folderDalMock.Object, _folderRepoMock.Object);


    //Act
    var actual = await _sut.GetFoldersByUserId(1);

    //Assert 
    Assert.Equal(expected.Count, actual.Count);

    for (int i = 0; i < expected.Count; i++)
    {
        Assert.Equal(expected[i].FolderName, actual[i].FolderName);
        Assert.Equal(expected[i].Size, actual[i].Size);
    }
}
```

If you really wanted to test against the correctness of the expression which handed over to `GetAllByFilter` by `GetFoldersByUserId` you need to do some extra work.
I personally used to match against the expression.ToString() result, according to your test case instead of `It.IsAny...`:

```csharp
Is.Is<Expression<Func<Folder, bool>>>(exp => exp.ToString() == "I => I.AppUserId == 1 && I.IsDeleted == false && I.ParentFolderId==null")
```

But to make this to work you should partially evaluate the expression before to explicitly replace encapsulated variable references and constant references with the actual value. Without this step `exp.ToString()` would look like this:

```
I => (((I.AppUserId == value(StackOverflow.UnitTest1+FolderManager+<>c__DisplayClass3_0).id) AndAlso (I.IsDeleted == False)) AndAlso (I.ParentFolderId == null))
```

where things like `StackOverflow.UnitTest1+FolderManager` would be the parts leading the actual encapsulated `id` variable's place in your code.

Instead of using the `exp.ToString()` method you can always modify your test to actually **use** the expression instead of match on it:

```csharp
// just populate to cover all special cases
private List<Folder> testFolderList = new List<Folder>()
{
    new Folder() { AppUserId=1, IsDeleted=false, ParentFolderId=null, FolderName = "a", Size = 1 },
    new Folder() { AppUserId=1, IsDeleted=true, ParentFolderId=null, FolderName = "b", Size = 2 },
    new Folder() { AppUserId=1, IsDeleted=false, ParentFolderId=2, FolderName = "c", Size = 3 },
    new Folder() { AppUserId=2, IsDeleted=false, ParentFolderId=null, FolderName = "a", Size = 4 },
};


[Fact]
public async Task GetFoldersByUserId_ShouldReturnListOfFolders_WhenUserExist()
{
    //Arrange
    var userId = 1;
    var expected = testFolderList
        // replace with expression based on the _contract_ you expect from GetFoldersByUserId
        .Where(I => I.AppUserId == userId && I.IsDeleted == false && I.ParentFolderId == null) 
        .ToList();

    var _folderRepoMock = new Mock<IGenericDal<Folder>>();
    _folderRepoMock
        .Setup(x => x.GetAllByFilter(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<Folder, bool>>>()))
        .ReturnsAsync((Expression<Func<Folder, bool>> exp) =>
        {
            return testFolderList
                // here we explicitly use the expression we got as parameter
                .Where(exp.Compile())
                .ToList();
        });

    var _folderDalMock = new Mock<IFolderDal>();

    var _sut = new FolderManager(_folderDalMock.Object, _folderRepoMock.Object);


    //Act
    var actual = await _sut.GetFoldersByUserId(userId);

    //Assert 
    Assert.Equal(expected.Count, actual.Count);

    for (int i = 0; i < expected.Count; i++)
    {
        Assert.Equal(expected[i].FolderName, actual[i].FolderName);
        Assert.Equal(expected[i].Size, actual[i].Size);
    }
}
```

This way the appropriateness of the constructed expression gets tested against your expectations given the test data.

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution. I will try it in other tests.